# How to plot several chunks of data contained in a single file?

Tags: python, r, matlab, matplotlib, gnuplot

I have a file that contains 2 columns divided into blocks. Each block has a header followed by some data. The blocks are separated from each other by an empty line. Something like:

```
x              y1
0              -65.950939
0.01417027519  -65.950969
0.02834055037  -65.950946
0.04251082556  -65.950961

x              y2
0              -39.797446
0.01417027519  -39.796663
0.02834055037  -39.794279
0.04251082556  -39.790951
:              :
```

How can I plot this file using either MATLAB, xmgrace, gnuplot or any other relevant tool?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it in **R**

```
# Your data
df <- read.table(text="x              y1
0              -65.950939
0.01417027519  -65.950969
0.02834055037  -65.950946
0.04251082556  -65.950961

x              y2
0              -39.797446
0.01417027519  -39.796663
0.02834055037  -39.794279
0.04251082556  -39.790951")

# Create indicator for blocks
df$tag <-  cumsum(grepl("[[:alpha:]]",df$V1))

# Reomve letters from columns
df <- df[!grepl("[[:alpha:]]",df$V1),]

# Convert to numerics
df[] <- sapply(df , as.numeric)

#plot
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df , aes(V1 , V2 )) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~tag  , scales="free")
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a file "data.dat", and assuming that you are working on linux and that you can use awk, this is what I would suggest :

- Use awk to remove the text and to display only the chunk of data you want to display
- Use the gnuplot internal for loop in order to display your data as distinct plots.

Here is a working **gnuplot** command if you want to try it by yourself. I use a for loop to display your two chunk of data, the trick being the system call to awk, the awk variable `a` being the "chunk index selector"

```
plot for [i=1:2] sprintf('< cat data.dat |  awk ''/./{ if ($1=="x") {a++} else if (a==%d) {print $0 }}''',i) u 1:2
```

This is the ugliest solution I ever found to a problem :)
But it works !!

[image: This is the resulting picture]

edit : You'll need a decent gnuplot version, I used gnuplot 4.6 patchlevel 3.